# Show a dummy text until image load in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a React Component, and a `JSON` which consists of image url, i pass the image url into image tag in my component through mapping function.

Here is a Example of my Code:

```js
import imgDetails from "../data/ImageDetails";

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imgContentLoad: false
    }
  }

  imageHandleLoad() {
    this.setState({
      imgContentLoad: true
    })
  }

  render() {
      return ({
            imgDetails.map((imgDetails) => {
                return ( <
                  React.Fragment > {
                    (this.state.imgContentLoad &&
                      <
                      img src = {
                        imgDetails.imgURL
                      }
                      onLoad = {
                        this.imageHandleLoad.bind(this)
                      }
                      />) || <
                      div > image is loading < /div>
                    } <
                    /React.Fragment>
                  )
                }
              )
            }
```

Here i want to display the "image is loading" text to show until the image loads so i wrote the above image onload function code. but my problem is, "image is loading" is showing infinitely the image is not showing. what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extract it to a new component that will listen to the `onload` event and return the `img` when its loaded

```
class ImageWithLoading extends React.Component {
  state = { isLoaded: false }

  componentDidMount() {
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
    image.src = this.props.src;
  }

  render() {
    const { src } = this.props;
    const { isLoaded } = this.state;

    return isLoaded
      ? <img src={src} />
      : <div>Loading image...</div>
  }
}
```

Then make the `Example` component just a container that maps the data to the `ImageWithLoading` component

```
const Example = () => imgDetails
  .map(({ imgURL }) => <ImageWithLoading key={imgURL} src={imgURL} />);
```

Comment: Hi @Asaf, Thanks for your solution, it works fine. i have a another doubt, how can i achieve the same if i have a string and a p tag. i want to show loading text until the actual strings loads from json.

Comment: @NandhiniKajol The loading state will never show, there is no need for it

Comment: @Asif, i want to show skeleton loader until a text and images comes. I implemented the skeleton loader, i used your image solution, its works super fine so now im asking for the texts.

Comment: @NandhiniKajol track the image state from `ImageWithLoading` and return both the image and the text from it when the image loads